# SLDS style not applied to pre-chat LWC on website outside of Salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, pre-chat

I have created a Lightning Web Component to be used as pre-chat.

When I test the Embedded Service Deployment, the SLDS styles are not being applied. I understand that this is now living on an external website (company website) and the stylying of this component is completely lost and the input fields look very basic (as lacking any stylying whatsoever).

This is what I have done so far to get some of the SLDS stylings to work:

```
import sldsCss from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/SLDS';
```

I went to the [Lightning Design System Website](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/downloads/#site-main-content) and downloaded the Static Resource without Icons.

I then run the the `LoadStyle` method to apply the CSS in the minified CSS.

```
    connectedCallback() {


        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, sldsCss)
            ]).then(() => {
                console.log( 'Files loaded' );
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log( error.body.message );
        });
}
```

I uploaded the `salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css` as a static resource. I am not sure if I am missing another file at this point or if the embedded service is still not ready for the lightning framework and if I should move back to Aura.